# Gcloud is not intiating the json rpc client in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, json-rpc

I have a nodejs app which is integrating to simplybook.me using jsonrpc. the integration is working good on my local server. but the client is failed to initialize when I run it over gcloud app.

file: index.js:
`

```
    const JSONRpcClient = require('../json-rpc');
    const apiUrl = 'https://user-api.simplybook.me';
    const SIMPLYBOOK_API_KEY = "[[REDACTED]]"
const SIMPLYBOOK_COMPANY_NAME = "dssdemo"

    const loginClient = new JSONRpcClient({
        url: `${apiUrl}/login`,
        onerror: (e:any)=>logger.error(e),
    });
    console.log("problem", loginClient);
    const clientToken = loginClient.getToken(SIMPLYBOOK_COMPANY_NAME, SIMPLYBOOK_API_KEY);

    logger.info('SimplyBook instantiated');`
```

file: json-rpc.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const logger_1 = require("../libs/logger");
/* eslint-disable */
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM('');
var jQuery = require("jquery")(dom.window);
/**
* JSON-RPC Client Exception class
*
* @param String code
* @param String message
*/
var JSONRpcClientException = function (code, message) {
    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
};
JSONRpcClientException.prototype = jQuery.extend(JSONRpcClientException.prototype, {
    /**
     * Magic method. COnvert object to string.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    toString: function () {
        return '[' + this.code + '] ' + this.message;
    }
});
/**
 * JSON-RPC Client
 *
 * @param Object options
 */
var JSONRpcClient = function (options) {
    JSONRpcClient.prototype.setOptions(options);
    JSONRpcClient.prototype.init();
};
JSONRpcClient.prototype = jQuery.extend(JSONRpcClient.prototype, {
    /**
     * Default options
     */
    options: {
        'onerror': function () { },
        'onsuccess': function () { },
        'url': '',
        'headers': {}
    },
    current: 1,
    onerror: null,
    onsuccess: null,
    onstart: null,
    /**
     * Init client
     */
    init: function () {
        this.onerror = this.getParam('onerror');
        this.onsuccess = this.getParam('onsuccess');
        this.initMethods();
    },
    /**
     * Init API methiods by url
     */
    initMethods: function () {
        var instance = this;
        // get all methods
        jQuery.ajax(this.getParam('url'), {
            'async': false,
            'success': function (data) {
                if (data.methods) {
                    // create method
                    jQuery.each(data.methods, function (methodName, methodParams) {
                        var method = function () {
                            var params = new Array();
                            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                                params.push(arguments[i]);
                            }
                            var id = (instance.current++);
                            var callback = params[params.length - 1];
                            var request = { jsonrpc: '2.0', method: methodName, params: params, id: id };
                            var async = false;
                            if (jQuery.type(callback) == 'function') {
                                async = true;
                                params.pop();
                            }
                            var res = null;
                            // API request
                            jQuery.ajax(instance.getParam('url'), {
                                'contentType': 'application/json',
                                'type': methodParams.transport,
                                'processData': false,
                                'dataType': 'json',
                                'cache': false,
                                'data': JSON.stringify(request),
                                'headers': instance.getParam('headers'),
                                'async': async,
                                'success': function (result) {
                                    if (jQuery.type(result.error) == 'object') {
                                        // res = JSONRpcClientException(result.error.code, result.error.message);
                                        // instance.onerror(res);
                                        logger_1.logger.info(result.error.message);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        res = result.result;
                                        if (jQuery.type(callback) == 'function') {
                                            callback(res);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    instance.onsuccess(res, id, methodName);
                                }
                            });
                            if (!async) {
                                return res;
                            }
                        };
                        instance[methodName] = method;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error("Methods could not be found");
                }
            }
        });
    },
    /**
     * Set client options
     *
     * @param Object options
     */
    setOptions: function (options) {
        this.options = jQuery.extend({}, this.options, options);
    },
    /**
     * Get client param, if param is not available in this.options return defaultValue
     *
     * @param String key
     * @param mixed defaultValue
     * @return mixed
     */
    getParam: function (key, defaultValue) {
        if (jQuery.type(this.options[key]) != 'undefined') {
            return this.options[key];
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
});
module.exports = JSONRpcClient;
//# sourceMappingURL=json-rpc.js.map
```

I have deployed my app using gcloud app deploy.

file: app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12
```

this is the problematic code. node my app is running and other features are working normally but this is problematic. which is running locally but not on the server and yes port is 8080.

[here is the screenshot of error on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQB00.png)
but it's working perfectly on my local
Please help and point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include more details. Please show the client configuration when it works locally and what you changed when you deployed to App Engine. Is the server running on port `8080`? This is a requirement for App Engine. Does your server bind to `0.0.0.0` (any) or `localhost` (== `127.0.0.1`). If the latter, that's also usually a problem. Please add more details about what you have, what you did so that we may understand your problem.

Comment: Could you please add more details in the issue you are experiecing, such as the code, configuration and the `app.yaml`  In stack overflow it is expected that when posting a question to include enogh information for the community to replicate the issue in order to help. This is also mentioned in this useful video on [How to ask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxSwhRSHeDQ)

Comment: @DazWilkin port is 8080, and app is ruuning but not this part

Comment: @SoniSol Please have a look now!

Comment: Will look when I get home. I removed your API key. Anyone with your key could use your account. I don't see the `server.js` or `package.json`. Those would be helpful.

Comment: project is very large otherwise and I am using typescript to translate everything on JS, just consider a simple express environment running index.js code

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand exactly what's going wrong but...

I built a simple gRPC-JSON example using the NPM [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-rpc-2.0).

I published the server as a Google Cloud Function and the client as an App Engine (standard) app.

The following works for me:

```sh
QUESTION="65449123"
PROJECT=dazwilkin-$(date +%y%m%d)-${QUESTION} && echo ${PROJECT}
BILLING=$(gcloud alpha billing accounts list --format="value(name)")

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

for SERVICE in cloudfunctions cloudbuild
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

gcloud app create \
--region=us-central \
--project=${PROJECT}


gcloud functions deploy server \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--source=./server \
--entry-point=server \
--runtime=nodejs14 \
--trigger-http \
--region=us-central1 \
--project=${PROJECT}

SERVER_URL=$(\
  gcloud functions describe server \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")


cd ./appengine

# Update `app.yaml` environment variable with server endpoint
sed --in-place "s|REPLACE|${SERVER_URL}|g" ./app.yaml

gcloud app deploy \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--quiet

CLIENT_URL=$(\
  gcloud app describe \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(defaultHostname)")

curl --request GET ${CLIENT_URL}
Hello Freddie
```

### Client

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "65449123",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "1.19.0",
        "express": "4.17.1",
        "json-rpc-2.0": "0.2.12",
        "node-fetch": "2.6.1"
    }
}
```

and:

`index.js`:

```js
const { JSONRPCClient, createJSONRPCErrorResponse } = require("json-rpc-2.0");

const express = require("express");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const SERVER_URL = (() => {
    let SERVER_URL = process.env.SERVER_URL
    console.log(SERVER_URL);
    return SERVER_URL
})();

const client = new JSONRPCClient(
    (jsonRPCRequest) =>
        fetch(SERVER_URL, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(jsonRPCRequest)
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json()
                  .then(jsonRPCResponse => client.receive(jsonRPCResponse));
            } else if (jsonRPCRequest.id !== undefined) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
            }
        })
);

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) =>
    client.request("echo", { text: "Hello Freddie" }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(result);
    })
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening: ${PORT}`);
})
```

> **NOTE** App Engine standard `require(express)` and I'm using `node-fetch` to mirror the NPM example

### Server

`app.yaml`:

```
runtime: nodejs12

env_variables:
  SERVER_URL: REPLACE
```

and:

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "65449123",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "1.19.0",
        "json-rpc-2.0": "0.2.12"
    }
}
```

and:

`index.js`:

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { JSONRPCServer } = require("json-rpc-2.0");

const server = new JSONRPCServer();

server.addMethod("echo", ({ text }) => text);
server.addMethod("log", ({ message }) => console.log(message));

exports.server = (req, res) => {
    const jsonRPCRequest = req.body;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonRPCRequest, null, 2));

    server.receive(jsonRPCRequest).then(jsonRPCResponse => {
        if (jsonRPCResponse) {
            res.json(jsonRPCResponse);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(204);
        }
    });
};
```